# Automatically encode and decode JSON saved to Element

Tags: array, json

I have a custom element with an array property, which is to be saved to the DB as JSON, and a corresponding query class:

```php
use craft\base\Element;

class Foo extends Element
{
    public array $columns;

    /**
     * @return FooQuery
     */
    private function getQueryClass(): FooQuery
    {
        return new FooQuery($this);
    }
}
```

As it stands trying to retrieve an element from the DB will throw:

```
Cannot assign string to property Foo::$columns of type array
```

Laravel handles this via a `casts` property on the model (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting). Is there an equivalent in Yii/Craft? If not, what is the best way to handle the transition from array to string (`json_encode`), when saving to the DB, and back when retrieving (`json_decode`), while maintaining PHP's type declaration?